# HTML forms that expand fill all the available space

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm rendering a form in a table with the labels in  tags (left) and text inputs in  tags (right of labels).
For the sake of flexibility, I'd like to write as little css as possible and have everything magically fall into place, such that:

1. the  cells expand to accomodate the width of the longest label
2. the  fields on the right expand to fill the whole width of the  cell

I've been trying various combinations of `width:100%` and `width:auto` on these various elements but to no avail. Is doing this possible, or should I just give up and specify hard widths like `width:Npx`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your code looks like (if you post, answers are so much better...).

Anyway: cells will expand naturally to the width of the longest element if no width is specified, BUT you can't have the element expand to the width of the cell at the same time! That would make the calculation of the width impossible. So I'd recommend fixing the inner content somehow. Input fields look great when they are all the same length...

Answer (score 0):

You have two options as far as I'm concerned. Either you implement a solution with tables that allows you to have fluid lengths for your labels, or you set them as fixed widths and use table-less markup. I personally see no compelling reason to choose one solution over the other, although some web developers will do almost anything to avoid using `<table>` elements in their markup.

That being said, this solution is quite easy if you are using tables: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/VcSXU/

```
td:first-child { 
    white-space: nowrap; /* don't allow text to wrap to the next line */
}
```